# Open chat on voice channel discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord, discord.js

I know I can send messages on a voice channel's chat panel as a discord user like so :

[image: Open chat]

[image: Message sent in the voice channel]

But I have no idea how to achieve the same thing using discord.js, there's absolutely nothing I can find about this on google, the official documentation or anywhere else??

For context, this is how I send messages on (for example) a text channel:

```js
client.channels.cache.get("id_of_the_channel").send('Test message !')
```

But if I try this with a voice channel, it tells me that `client.channels.cache.get(...).send is not a function`, while I'm sure to having copied the good id since my `channelinfo` command works with this id and that my bot is in the server of the channel, therefore I guess `VoiceChannel`s don't have a `send` method.

So, how to do the same on those voice channels?

Comment: Well, isn't it the same for voice channels? I'm pretty sure it works like that. What problems did you have?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros it tells me that client.channels.cache.get(...).send is not a function while I'm sure to having copied the good id since my `channelinfo` command works with this id and that my bot is in the server of the channel, therefore I guess VoiceChannels don't have a send method

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I've just tested it in `v13.8.1` and works as expected. What's your discord.js version?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Oh my version is `^13.7.0` would updating will fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's only available in `v13.8.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`VoiceChannel#send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceChannel) is only available from [`v13.8.0`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/13.8.0), so you'll need to upgrade your discord.js to use [this feature](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/6921).

Comment: is it possible to detect when users send messages in a voice channel?
Eg) user sends a certain emoji to a voice channel, bot does something based on emoji. Something like that

Comment: Sure, you can check the message's channel. Something like this should work: `client.on('messageCreate', (message) => { if (message.channel.type === ChannelType.GuildVoice) doSomething(); });`.